# 3D coordinate Transformation

Tags: geometry, transformation, 3d

I am currently trying to align two bodies which do not have similar sizes and shapes. But both of these two bodies share some keynodes(similar nodal position with 0.1% error difference). How can I find the translation and rotation matrix to move body A to body B with the 27 keynodes that I have found from these two bodies?

Keynodes:

Body A:
Node 1: (12.858 39.705 24.813), Node 2: (12.741 41.362 23.5190), Node 3: (13.328 40.423 23.174)

Body B:
Node 2: (28.909 41.108 20.323), Node 2: (29.685 40.785 20.507), Node 3: (29.093 40.247 20.814)

Thousand thanks and appreciation for any supports in advance.

Best,
adexim

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I really appreciate it but could you explain more on why is it impossible to accomplish this with a translation and rotation and is it important to find the distance between the points on each body system? If I only have one set of point from each bodies. Say:

Point A: 12.858 39.705 24.813
Point B: 12.741 41.362 23.5190

Can I find the rotation and translation matrix with only one point data from each bodies respectively?

Comment: Rotations and translations *do not change relative distances between points*. The way I understand your question, you've marked three points on an object and then moved the object. The distances between the moved points should be the same as the distances between the unmoved points.

Comment: I see..I understand what you meant already. Thanks!! So I will have to do some scaling first in order to move the points right? Like:

P2 = T + R.S [P1]

T = Translation
R = Rotation
S = Scaling

Comment: If you are truly confident that your points haven't been typoed, then yes, you could seek an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) between the two triples of points. That would encompass a lot more than just rotation, translation and scaling.

Comment: Thanks!!! Help appreciated!!!

Comment: OK, if this is going to remain your question, I'm going to convert my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have typoed point data, or else didn't realize that you'd also need skewing in your transformation, because there is no way to accomplish this with a translation and rotation.

Such a transformation would preserve distances, but the distances between the first three points are $\{8.6238,0.848528,8.86397\}$ and the distances between the points of the second set are $\{1.68819,0.9,1.74929\}$. These are significantly different and can't be explained by measurement error.

A transformation between these two point sets would have to be composed of more than rigid Euclidean motions: it would need to have some affine transformation that includes some skewing.